# C# WPF Time Until xx

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, countdown

I am trying to display the time remaining until a time specified by the user. I want to show Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and maybe milliseconds until the specified time.

```
DateTime remaining = DateTime.Parse("2/24/2014 18:00:00 pm");
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = remaining - startDate;
string countdown = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
CountDown.Content = countdown;
```

Visual Studio says I need to parse the string to take in the date before setting it to a DateTime object.

So do I need to create a new string, then parse it to a string, and then set the string to a DateTime object?

**Update:**

The actual error message I am receiving is:

> System.FormatException was unhandled HResult=-2146233033
>   Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Source=mscorlib

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Visual Studio says..."?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want:

```
DateTime target = new DateTime(2014, 2, 24, 18, 0, 0);
TimeSpan remaining = target - DateTime.Now;
```

There's no need to parse a string just to get a `DateTime` value, if you already know the year/month/day etc you want.

However, you've also talked about "a time specified by the user". If that date/time is being specified as a string, then yes, you'll need to parse it. Ideally, it would be specified by some sort of date/time picker control, in which case you should just be able to get an appropriate `DateTime` value. Avoid string conversions unless you really need them.

Comment: Jon knows time (watched your Plurasight videos... good lord, I never knew time was so complex).

Comment: @Noobacode: I'm hoping to do a whole (short) Pluralsight course *just* on handling dates and times in Java and .NET.

Comment: Jon, that would be awesome!

Comment: Yes, I meant that when I debugged the program, VS errored and told me what I said above. Yes, I want the user to be able to pick this time but, for now I was just trying to find what I was doing wrong. So, DateTime is an array. Will the DatePicker WPF control allow a user to select a time?

Comment: @Error418: What do you mean by "told me what I said above"? You need to be *far* more precise - what error did you get, and where? And what do you mean by "So, DateTime is an array" - no it's not, it's a type...

Comment: @Error418: And no, it doesn't look like DatePicker itself lets you pick a time, but if you search for "date time picker control WPF" you'll get lots of hits for alternatives.

Comment: System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: @Error418: Right - I'm not sure how you expected us to guess that that's what happened from "Visual Studio says I need to parse the string". But hopefully what I've written so far will help...

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
DateTime remaining = DateTime.Parse("2/24/2014 18:00:00 pm");
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = remaining - startDate;
DateTime difference = new DateTime(t.Ticks);
CountDown.Content = difference;
```